# Django dynamic FileField upload_to

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, filefield, django-file-upload

I'm trying to make dynamic upload path to FileField model. So when user uploads a file, Django stores it to my computer /media/(username)/(path_to_a_file)/(filename).

E.g. /media/Michael/Homeworks/Math/Week_1/questions.pdf or /media/Ernie/Fishing/Atlantic_ocean/Good_fishing_spots.txt

```
VIEWS
@login_required
def add_file(request, **kwargs):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user

        post.parent = Directory.objects.get(directory_path=str(kwargs['directory_path']))
        post.file_path = str(kwargs['directory_path'])

        post.file_content = request.FILES['file_content'] <-- need to pass dynamic file_path here

        post.save()
        return redirect('/home/' + str(post.author))

MODELS
class File(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Directory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file_path = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    file_content = models.FileField(upload_to='e.g. /username/PATH/PATH/..../')

FORMS
class AddFile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['file_name', 'file_content']
```

What I have found was this, but after trial and error I have not found the way to do it. So the "upload/..." would be post.file_path, which is dynamic.

```
def get_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'upload/%d/%s' % (instance.profile, filename)


class Upload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_to)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use some thing like this(i used it in my project):

```
import os
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(
      "user_%d" % instance.owner.id, "car_%s" % instance.slug, filename)
```

Now:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the `file_path` is an attribute on the `File` model, can you not build the full path something like this:

```py
import os

def create_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(
        instance.author.username,
        instance.file_path,
        filename
    )
```

And then reference it from your `File` model:

```py
class File(models.Model):
    ...
    file_content = models.FileField(upload_to=create_path)
```

[Link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Comment: When `filename` is two words, e.g. `NRB 2708`, it ends up as `NRB_2708`. How can I avoid/override the underscore to end up with `NRB 2708`?

Comment: @Gathide `return filename.replace('_', ' ')`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers work flawlessly; however, I want to point out the line in the source code that allows such functionality. You can view the function, `generate_filename`, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/49ca6bbc445cb75ee742b215f5f90465ad8e7309/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L309), in Django's source code.

The lines that make the magic happen:

```py
if callable(self.upload_to):
    filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)
```

When you pass a `callable` to the `upload_to` parameter, Django will call the `callable` to generate the path. Note that Django expects your `callable` to handle two arguments:

- `instance`

  - the model that contains the `FileField`/`ImageField`
- `filename`

  - the name of the uploaded file, *including the extension* (.png, .pdf, ...)

Also note that Python does not force your `callable`'s arguments to be exactly 'instance' and 'filename' because Django passes them as positional parameters. For example, I prefer to rename them:

```py
def get_file_path(obj, fname):
    return os.path.join(
        'products',
        obj.slug,
        fname,
    )
```

And then use it like so:

```py
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```