# Django ImageField Creating New Folder by ID on upload?

Tags: django, database, django-models, optimization, organization

I'm Currently developing a app with a ManyToMany ImageField Relantionship . I want to have the ImageField save all images to a specific folder based on the ID of the Relantionship.

I want to have something like this.

class PostImages(models.Model):

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Post_Images/post/' + post.id)
```

class Post(models.Model):

```
images = models.ManyToManyField(PostImages)
```

How do I access the post.id to do this ? I mostly want to do this for organization purposes right now cause its on my local machine but also see no reason to change it when I deploy.

Comment: You could have a look to a related question already ask:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591304/django-dynamic-filefield-upload-to

Answer (score 0):

E.g. based on FileField^ but the same you can use for ImageField:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    return instance.created.strftime("folder/%Y/%m/%d/") + instance.post.id

bfile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path, null=True)
```

Comment: Im confused in this example what are the instance and filename parameters referencing ?

Comment: You can check what they are in doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to